# Can we delete the Resources folder in Laravel after building the project?

Tags: php, laravel, webpack, bundler, vite

In Laravel 9 where it uses **Vite** to bundle the js and css files, after running

```
npm run build
```

it created the bundled js and css files inside **public/build** folder.

Can we now delete the original js and css files that are created inside resources? or to upload the project to hosting without this resources folder?

Also, if I have other css/js files but not inside Resources folder, should I add them manually to the **input** array inside the **vite.config.js** file to get them compiled and bundled ?

Thanks

Comment: For what purpose do you want to do this?

Comment: @ceejayoz to reduce the total size of my project on the shared hosting (and maybe the performance?), and also to check if I am understanding the mechanism and purpose of vite correctly..

Comment: It won't help performance, and you're likely talking about a couple megabytes at most. If your shared hosting is that stingy, it's time to change hosts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the assets you have in `resources` directory.

This directory can hold un-compiled front-end assets such as CSS or JavaScript  - those will be bundled and available in `public` folder and served from there, therefore it's safe to delete them on the shared hosting.

However, this directory can also hold backend assets like views, and those files will be read by Laravel directly on shared hosting. If you delete them, your Laravel application will crash.

Therefore, **if the only assets you have in the folder are frontend ones** that are bundled and served from `public`, it is safe to remove this directory, howevever **there won't be any performance improvement** coming from that.

Comment: thanks a lot!!! helped me.. one more thing, if I want to add my own js/css files, should I add them to resources to get them compiled/bundled? or can I put them somewhere else and point to that directory inside vite.config.js?